# libx264 encode error Input picture width (40) is greater than stride (0)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, libx264

I used libx264 in ffmpeg to encode video, I used the configuration below.

```
enCodecContext->bit_rate = 300000;
enCodecContext->width = 80;
enCodecContext->height = 60;
enCodecContext->time_base = (AVRational) {1, 25};
enCodecContext->gop_size = 10;
enCodecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
enCodecContext->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
enCodecContext->qcompress = 0.6;
av_opt_set(enCodecContext->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);
```

But when I called `avcodec_encode_video2` with `enCodecContext`, I got the error `Input picture width (40) is greater than stride (0)`.

```
avcodec_encode_video2(enCodecContext, &filteredAVPacket, pFilteredAVFrame, &got_packet_ptr);
```

The `pFilteredAVFrame->width` and `pFilteredAVFrame->height` is `80` and `60` respectively.

Did I missed something when configured `libx264`, How can I get a workable configuration for `libx264` to encode my video?

Comment: I see a [recent fix](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=d1050d9950610aa2b27878b67bb2b902dd717e7c) for this problem. Maybe your ffmpeg is not up-to-date?

Comment: @AlexCohn My ffmpeg version is 2.8.2, and I thought this version has already apply this patch.

Answer (score 2):

x264 is fine. You must fill in the AVPicture.linestride variable for your image planes. The stride describes how the image is laid out in memory. The stride must be at least as big as the image width. In the case of YUV 4:2:0, the stride must be at least half the width on the second and third plane.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa473780(v=vs.85).aspx